How to know if a filter is active inside a matrix
I am using DimensionA as a visual filter on my page, then I am using the same dimension in my matrix.
I am using a measure to control that at least one value has been filtered from my filter. I use the ISFILTERED Function, which works fine outside the matrix, but inside the matrix no.
the measure is like that:
measure = IF(ISFILTERED(DimensionA),CALCULATE(SUM(Fact(colA))),Blank())

So outside the matrix works fine, but inside the matrix, the measure is just showing data whatever is my selection.
Any idea on how to control what is filtered outside the matrix?
Many thanks!

You can use ALLSELECTED() here to remove the context within the Matrix visual of the Dimension. Try something like:
var isDimFiltered = CALCULATE( ISFILTERED(DimensionA), ALLSELECTED(DimensionA) )
return IF( isDimFiltered, SUM(Fact[colA]) )


From what you are saying I can say that because ISFILTERED is checking if the column is filtered in the current filter context but inside a matrix the filter context for the dimension being used in rows or columns inherently includes those row or column values.
Try :
Measure = 
IF(
    HASONEVALUE(DimensionA[ColumnA]), 
    CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[colA])),
    BLANK()
)

If you have to check whether any value has been selected in the slicer or filter and not necessarily just one value :
Measure = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(VALUES(DimensionA[ColumnA])) > 0,
    CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[colA])),
    BLANK()
)

